# Buildozer error - `Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match`

Tags: python, kivy, ubuntu-18.04, buildozer

I have a working kivy application, and am trying to turn it into an app using buildozer (using Ubuntu 18.04 in virtualbox on a windows PC). I created a `buildozer.spec` file using `buildozer init`, and then I ran `buildozer -v android` debug in terminal. After a few minutes, I got a long error message which stated that the command failed at the requirements line in the `buildozer.spec` file. Above that, there was a very long list of `Skipping link` messages (5 of which I have shown below). The ones below are in reference to `pandas`, but I also saw some linking to `aiohttp`, and probably some other python packages.

```
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp36-cp36m-win_amd64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/ac/92c3d2f0b627efbd1a7b2156faa697f9c2bbd7b0fe83ba8a9d36f982156f/pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=26382aab9c119735908d94d2c5c08020a4a0a82969b7e5eefb92f902b3b30ad7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/b5/bab3477466a4d9e705d40829ac65683155e7977acbc07f05b06fabded1be/pandas-0.25.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#sha256=00dff3a8e337f5ed7ad295d98a31821d3d0fe7792da82d78d7fd79b89c03ea9d (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/e0/a1b39cdcb2c391f087a1538bc8a6d62a82d0439693192aef541d7b123769/pandas-0.25.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=e45055c30a608076e31a9fcd780a956ed3b1fa20db61561b8d88b79259f526f7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp37-cp37m-win32: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/7d/54f09000634dc90eb3662500517feffe243a40cfc9cbd4e1a099b47de6b5/pandas-0.25.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl#sha256=255920e63850dc512ce356233081098554d641ba99c3767dde9e9f35630f994b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp37-cp37m-win_amd64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/d0/1e8e60e61e748338e3a40e42f5dfeee63ccdecfc4f0894122b890bfb009a/pandas-0.25.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=22361b1597c8c2ffd697aa9bf85423afa9e1fcfa6b1ea821054a244d5f24d75e (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3)
  Skipp... (13086 more, please see e.stdout)
```

Does it have something to do with having to make a recipe for these packages? Have I got to do that? I originally suspected that, seeing as aiohttp may not be a commonly used package, but pandas certainly is, so I am not sure if the issue is related to recipes.

---

**Question:** What is going wrong?

Comment: When a package is mentioned in "p4a recipes" than it will certainly be built. When the package only contains python code it will probably work. When there are precompiled libs a new recipe could help.

Comment: Pandas is not supported on android, that's a root cause of the failure to find a wheel for it.

Comment: @inclement so what is the solution to this? I must create a recipe or find a way to not use pandas in my program?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.